# USB install of Linux Mint - only shows up as a single partition but i've ran out of space

Tags: linux-mint, partition, live-usb

I recently set up an installation of Linux Mint Maya 13.2 on a USB stick.  I set it up with UNetBootin (http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).  When this sets up the drive, it makes a "regular" partition and a persistence partition to enable the install to persist between reboots (i.e. to not just act like a DVD).

Within the installation, I've run out of space.  The drive is 14.64 GiB in total, and when I do `df -h` in the install, I see this:

```
$ df -h
df: `/cow': No such file or directory
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          4.0G  3.8G     0 100% /
udev            1.2G  4.0K  1.2G   1% /dev
tmpfs           465M  988K  464M   1% /run
/dev/sdb1        15G  5.0G  9.8G  34% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      869M  869M     0 100% /rofs
/cow            4.0G  3.8G     0 100% /
tmpfs           1.2G   16K  1.2G   1% /tmp
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.2G  144K  1.2G   1% /run/shm
```

`rootfs` seems to be what I have available to use. `/dev/sdb1` is the usb drive. I'm not sure what's happened to the "persistence" partition.

When I set it up, I allocated 10G (the maximum allowed) to the persistence partition, thinking that this would be where all my data, files etc would be stored so I'd better make it have the majority of the space.  However, it looks like everything that I'm doing (installing, copying over etc) is using up the smaller partition, which is around 4 GB.

Hmm, I thought, maybe I should change it so that the persistence partition is smaller, and give more space to the "main" partition.  So, I looked at the drive in `gparted` in a different computer, and saw this:

[image: gparted looking at the drive from a different computer]

which looks like it's all one big partition.  If I run `gparted` inside the problem OS, I see the same thing.

Can anyone advise how I can give myself more space?

Comment: 1 fat32 partition looks normal to me for a liveUSB. If you want a real linux installation on the drive, UNetbootin is not what you are looking for, you will have to do the installation manually.

Comment: That doesn't sound like good news @switch87 - would you mind explaining what you mean by "real" and why UNetbootin isn't up to the task?

Comment: UNetbootin is a program to make a liveUSB, or with other words liveDVD on a stick, it is a read only system, everything you do on it vanishes after reboot.It is a 1 fat32 partition, the other partitions are created on your ram

Comment: But i have been using it with persistence, ie my changes remain after reboot.  It's just that i've ran out of space.

Comment: I don't know if this would be better, but try `dd` the image and use `GNOME Disks` to create a partition from the remaining space.

Comment: http://www.linux.com/community/blogs/133-general-linux/420179-creating-a-debian-live-usb-flash-drive-with-persistence-for-non-techies

Comment: Thanks @switch87 but that is more like a "starting from total scratch" suggestion than a "fixing it" suggestion.

Comment: I've fixed this, in a way which involved losing my existing changes but not totally starting from scratch - see my answer below.  Thanks for thinking about this everyone.

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering my own question because this is a bit too long for a comment.  I've fixed this, but it involved wiping out all my changes and starting from scratch.

I basically followed "Method 0" from this page, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent, which involves removing a file called `casper-rw`, which stores the persistent changes and is limited in size to 4G due to the FAT32 file system (which sets a maximum file size of 4GB), and replacing it with a new partition labelled `casper-rw`, which is ext2 (can be ext3 or ext4 but I did ext2 as that was the default which gparted came up with.)  The install seems happy with the replacement, and now `df -h` says I have 14GB available in my main working partition.

So, like I said, this involved losing all my changes so far, but I'm now starting again with a 14G usable persistent space in my USB install.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! Just so you know, answering your own question is completely fine and [even encouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132886/203101). It would also be great if you could remember to come back and accept this as soon as the system allows you to.

Comment: Thanks - i will wait to see if someone comes back with a solution which doesn't wipe out my existing changes, since that would be even better :)